# Editable span has a label below CSS HTML

Tags: html, css

```css
span.contenteditable[contenteditable] {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.contenteditable[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    display: inline-block;
    color:red;
}
span.contenteditable[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
    content: attr(data-focused-advice);
    color:red;
}
```

```html
I, <span type="text" id="printownername" class="underline contenteditable" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please Type Name" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span> , of legal age, <span type="text" id="printownercitizenship" class="underline contenteditable" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please Type Citizenship" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span> <span type="text" id="printownercivilstatus" class="underline contenteditable" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please Type Civil Status" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span> and with postal address at<br>
                <small><i> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; (Citizenship) &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; (Civil Status)</i></small><br>
                <span type="text" id="printowneraddress" class="underline contenteditable" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please type" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span>, after having been duly sworn to in accordance with law hereby depose and say:<br>
                <br>
```

I have this editable span which has a label below. I want to make the label lock into the span. When I say lock where ever the span is I want the label to be always below the span.

I dont have any idea how to do this.

I want the label `(Citizenship)` to be always below the editable span with Place holder like text `Please Type Citizenship`. So that user the Input Date Citizenship has the label below it .

***I want all label to always below their respective editable span***

Sample Expected about is.

```
Canadian

(Citizenship)
```

Comment: what are you expecting ? be more clear

Comment: Which label are we talking about? There is no `<label>`, and there are several contenteditable spans. Maybe put up a mock screenshot of how you want it to look.

Comment: Well, that would be much easier if you could turn the #printownercitizenship span into a block instead of an inline-block, but I guess that's not an option? You want the word "(Citizenship)" be below it, no matter where the span is horizontally on the line? Hm. Let me think

Comment: @MrLister yes you are right as well as the other label to be below their respective editable span.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to solve this is similar to the idea of *ruby annotation*, the only exception being that the annotation is below the baseline instead of above.

So I put a container around the span and its note, that I made inline-block, and made the note a block.

```css
span.contenteditable[contenteditable] {
    display: inline-block;
}
span.contenteditable[contenteditable]:empty::before {
    content: attr(data-placeholder);
    display: inline-block;
    color:red;
}
span.contenteditable[contenteditable]:empty:focus::before {
    content: attr(data-focused-advice);
    color:red;
}
.annotate {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top}
.annotate small {display:block; font-style:italic;}
```

```html
I, <span type="text" id="printownername" class="underline contenteditable"
contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please Type Name"
data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span>, of legal age,
<span class="annotate"><span type="text" id="printownercitizenship"
contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please Type Citizenship"
class="underline contenteditable" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span>
<small>(Citizenship)</small></span>
<span class="annotate"><span type="text" id="printownercivilstatus"
class="underline contenteditable" data-placeholder="Please Type Civil Status" 
contenteditable="true" data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span>
<small>(Civil Status)</small></span>
and with postal address at<br>
<span type="text" id="printowneraddress" class="underline contenteditable"
contenteditable="true" data-placeholder="Please type"
data-focused-advice="Start typing"></span>,
after having been duly sworn to in accordance with law hereby depose and say:<br>
<br>
```

(Also note that I'm not a great fan of horizontal scrollbars, so I formatted the HTML differently, but that shouldn't matter for the results.)

Comment: this is it but can you add more explanation just so people and i can understand thank you

Comment: great happy coding :)

Comment: OK, done, but there shouldn't be much confusion for people who know about ruby annotation and its implementation in HTML.